# Conditions for $p^m-2$ to be a prime power for a prime $p$ and a positive integer $m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose we are given a prime number $p$ and a positive integer $m$. Can we give a **general condition** on $(p,m)$ pairs such that $p^m-2$ is a prime power?

Edit: I am looking for a constructive method (i.e., achievable set of pairs) rather than a converse. Of course, a converse would be more than welcome!

Comment: ${}p = m = 3{}$.

Comment: sure, p=m=2 also but I am looking for a general condition similar to the condition for Fermat numbers.

Comment: If you allow primes themselves to be prime powers then there might be infinite. If not, $p=m=3$ is the unique solution.

Comment: I think this should work, @oneoneonezero : $x \nmid \sqrt{p} \forall x : x \in \mathbb{N}, x < \sqrt{p}$.

Comment: No, p should be a prime number, not prime power. And I do not think that p=m=3 is unique. p=m=2 and p=3 with m=2 also satisfy!

Comment: Well, my condition guarantees you that you get primes (Not mine alone ! It has been proven since time immemorial)..

Comment: Now for the prime powers, I'd suggest modifying the conditions.

Comment: Hey, what about this :  $x \nmid \sqrt[2m]{p} \forall x : x \in \mathbb{N}, x < \sqrt[2m]{p}$.

Comment: (Pillai’s Conjecture) For any integer $k ≥ 1$, the Diophantine equation
$a^x − b^y = k$ has only finitely many positive integer solutions $(a, b, x, y)$, with $x ≥ 2$ and $y ≥ 2$.

It still remains a conjecture and not proven.

See: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/PerfectPowers.pdf for work on this family of Diophantine equations.

Comment: My answer is just a conjecture... I leave it to all of you to verify it.

Comment: @oneoneonezero: The given equation can be written as $p^m - q^n = 2, q$ prime. It is same as $a^x - b^y = k$ in my comment with variable substitution. Pillai's conjecture doesn't even specify that $(a,b)$ have to be primes, so it is a generalization of the problem posed. However, Pillai's conjecture remains unproven for a long time. So, it is possible we may encounter interesting results.

Comment: You have to fix $k = 2$...

Comment: I now see your point. k=2, and p and q are prime. I guess, the condition that they are prime might allow some better results.

Comment: But I feel that primes with a greater difference between them may produce a difference greater than $2$ when taken to their $m$th and $n$th powers, right ?

Comment: @Spectre It is not clear as (P,m) and (q,n) are allowed to be very different values, I mean in terms of how large each of them is.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this :  $x \nmid \sqrt[2m]{p} \space \forall \space x : x \in \mathbb{N}, x < \sqrt[2m]{p}$. This is just a conjecture of mine, but of course you can try placing $(p^m - 2)$ for $p$ and $2n$ for $2m$ in my conjecture statement.

**My Thoughts**

---

1. For sure , you can ascertain that $p \neq 2$, since $2^m - 2 = 2(2^{m - 1} - 1)$
   is a composite number that is not a positive integer power of $2$.
2. (Derived from what @vvgiri said) If we equate $p^m - 2$ to some $q^n$ ($q$ is a prime), you can formulate a condition as follows:
   $$\because p^m - 2 = q^n ,p^m = q^n + 2\implies p =\sqrt[m]{q^n + 2} \space\text{and}  \space m = \log_p(q^n + 2) (m \in \mathbb{Z}^+)$$
   Now that you have something to decide the values of $p$ and $m$ , try changing $q$ and $n$ (or, find pairs of the type $(q,n)$)such that the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: This is the simplest condition for $(p^m - 2)$ that I can provide.

Comment: What is already proven? The version with m=1 in your condition?

Comment: I have no idea.... but I leave it to you all.. mine is a conjecture

Comment: @oneoneonezero There's a condition to prove the primality of numbers (smaller ones, I guess). The same condition, when applied here, may work, if you take the $2n^{th}$ power of $(p^m - 2)$.

Comment: I see, this does not help much but I will look at it. Hopefully someone else can comment on it too!

Comment: I am just 15 years old.. so I may be senseless (but it is worth trying)

Comment: My brain took the decision as follows : since the whole thing had to be the power of a prime, the $n$th root of $p^m- 2$ should be prime. So, taking the expression down to its $\frac{1}{n}^{th}$ power should work.

Comment: The only disadvantage in my method is that you can't properly determine which power of which prime is that $p^m - 2$.

Comment: I did not mean to judge your comments, I was just being hopeful that someone else can give a clearer path to me. Keep up the good work @Spectre!!

Comment: Therefore, another method I suggest is that you have find a prime $P$ such that $\log_{P}(p^m - 2) \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: @oneoneonezero , I know that you weren't judging me..

Comment: I am looking for constructive methods, so it does not still help much yet.

Comment: I know.. I put up what I knew...

Comment: Never mind :) I'll learn something new if I wait for a better answer to this question.

Comment: I agree that $p,q\neq 2$ but you need the additional condition that m>2; otherwise, p=m=2 work. Playing around and searching for numbers is fine but it does not seem to give a general structure. For instance, $(p,m)=(2,2), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4),(5,2),(7,2)$ all work.

Comment: I didn't say anything about $q$ ! :)

Comment: I left the rest to you to gauge out ! 